# Need optimal code for .zshrc to source file after curl

Tags: zsh

I am having issues with my .zshrc file setting up my zplugin for a first-time run. Its purpose is to fetch the installer from zplug github, run the shell install, then source it.

This is my .zshrc file:

```
# Check if zplug is installed
if [[ ! -d ~/.zplug ]]; then
    curl -sL --proto-redir -all,https https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zplug/installer/master/installer.zsh | zsh
fi

source ~/.zplug/init.zsh
```

And this is the output from starting up my terminal:

```
✔  Checking if your zsh version is newer than 4.1.9 [SUCCEEDED]
✔  Installing zplug to /home/thomas/.zplug [SUCCEEDED]
All processes are successfully completed 
For more information, see http://zplug.sh 
Enjoy zplug!
/home/dwarfoz/.zshrc:source:8: no such file or directory: /home/dwarfoz/.zplug/init.zsh
```

Install succeeds but sourcing fails :(

So I think this might be some sort of race condition. I put a sleep timer for two seconds after curl.

```
# Check if zplug is installed
if [[ ! -d ~/.zplug ]]; then
    curl -sL --proto-redir -all,https https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zplug/installer/master/installer.zsh | zsh
    sleep 2
fi

source ~/.zplug/init.zsh
```

And indeed it works. (terminal output omitted here)

So I'm wondering if there's a way to source the file as soon curl completes -- without waiting some arbitrary amount of time like 2 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a `|cat`. That's a way to force the waiting of processes started in background. `cat` in effect will wait for them while waiting for the end of its input. That works because those background processes keep the pipe `cat` is reading from open (as long as their standard output is not redirected). So:

```
curl -sL --proto-redir -all,https https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zplug/installer/master/installer.zsh | zsh | cat
```

The same effect can be achieved with:

```
: $(curl -sL --proto-redir -all,https https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zplug/installer/master/installer.zsh | zsh)
```

Still a pipe, but this time, created by `zsh` for the command substitution.

I can't help mentioning that running foreign code like that as part of your `~/.zshrc` makes me very uncomfortable.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source file it seems that this script runs `git clone https://github.com/zplug/zplug.git $ZPLUG_HOME` in the background via function `execute()` and, not waiting for this process to finish, announces message `SUCCEEDED` and exits.

You have basically two options:

- wait for the script to create a file for example by adding while loop, something like

  ```
  while [[ ! -f ~/.zplug/init.zsh ]]; do
     sleep 1
  done
  ```

  Check your `sleep` implementation, if it supports floating numbers then try `sleep 0.1` if time is an issue, or even wait with inotify to be a little (marginally) more efficient.
- modify this installation script to wait for its internal jobs. It is on git so you can fork it or ask the author to do this.